AM335x ICE EVM Rev2.1 it seems the datasheet, BOM, and schematic don't align more details down is there any s MT41J128M16JT-125 (84-ball FBGA package)
In TI’s document for the ICE design, they specify a 2 Gbit DDR3 SDRAM with part number MT41J128M16JT-125 in an 84-ball FBGA package. However, when searching on Micron’s official site and distributor platforms like Mouser, there’s no 84-ball FBGA version for this part in their catalog.
To make things more confusing, there's a discrepancy in the ball assignments for the same part number between the TI documentation and the available Micron datasheets. TI specifies ball T7 as A14, but in Micron’s datasheet, A14 is marked as NC (No Connect).
Despite multiple attempts, I haven’t been able to reach either TI or Micron for clarification.
Supplier Requirements: Both companies restrict access to full documentation for those with official company emails, making it difficult for freelancers or smaller entities.
Documentation Consistency: It’s hard to design with confidence when the documentation isn’t aligned, especially for critical components like DDR3 memory.
Any insights from others who’ve faced similar challenges with DDR3 sourcing or documentation inconsistencies? How do you navigate these issues, particularly as an independent engineer?
I noticed also in the design files of TI https://www.ti.com/tool/TMDSICE3359#design-files
the BOM says they used 96-ball which does not match the hardware guide below

micron DDR3 SDRAM part catalog
https://www.micron.com/products/memory/dram-components/ddr3-sdram/part-catalog?density=2Gb
datasheet
https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/671/2Gb_DDR3_SDRAM-1283766.pdf
hardware guide "AM335x ICE EVM Rev2.1 Hardware User Guide"
https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spruip3/spruip3.pdf?ts=1730627742728&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Ftool%252FTMDSICE3359

Please change the links from using https://lnkd.in to point at the actual manufactures web site. I'm wary of following such short links as not sure if might point as spam or malware.

To investigate this:

In TI’s document for the ICE design, they specify a 2 Gbit DDR3 SDRAM with part number MT41J128M16JT-125 in an 84-ball FBGA package. However, when searching on Micron’s official site and distributor platforms like Mouser, there’s no 84-ball FBGA version for this part in their catalog.

There have been two versions of the AM3359 Industrial Communications Engine:

Rev 1.0 which is obsolete.
Rev 2.1 which is still available.

The AM335x ICE EVM Rev2.1 Hardware User's Guide contains the following in section 4.5.1 DDR3 SDRAM:

The ICE design contains 2 Gbit (128M × 16) of DDR3 SDRAM memory. The part number for the DDR3 SDRAM memory used is MT41J128M16JT-125. The package used is an 84-ball FBGA package.

The Micron MT41J128M16JT-125:K page contains:

Pin Count : 96-ball

Therefore, there is a discrepancy as per the question.
While the AN3359 ICE Rev 1.0 information no longer appears on the main TI web site, found the TI forum thread TMDXICE3359 Gerber files which contains attachments for the Rev 1.0 schematics and PCB layout. The 1122.AM335x_ICE_3h0013_Schematic_Rev1_0B.pdf shows the Rev 1.0 uses a DDR2 SDRAM part MT47H128M16RT-25E:C. The Micron MT47H128M16RT-25E:C page contains:

Pin Count : 84-ball

Therefore, when the AM3359 ICE was changed from Rev 1.0 Rev 2.1 the SDRAM was changed from a 84-ball DDR2 to 96-ball DDR3 device. However, it looks like the Rev 2.1 user's manual was left with an error which says the DDR3 MT41J128M16JT-125 used has 84 balls rather than 96 balls.
I found an old Rev 1.0 AM3359 ICE and the SDRAM U7 has FBGA Code D9MTD which the Micron FBGA and component marking decoder says is part number MT47H128M16RT-25E:C. I.e. the device fitted to an actual Rev 1.0 board matches the part shown in the schematic attached to the TI forum thread above.

Any insights from others who’ve faced similar challenges with DDR3 sourcing or documentation inconsistencies?

As a general guide I think schematics and BOMs are more likely to be correct on part details since they are used to be able to design and manufacture a PCB. Whereas user guides may have typos, as suspect happened in this case when the user guide for Rev 2.1 was produced.
In this case since I had previously used a AM3359 ICE Rev 1.0 it helped to trigger a memory to look for board revision specific differences.

TI specifies ball T7 as A14, but in Micron’s datasheet, A14 is marked as NC (No Connect).

The MT41J128M16JT-125 is organised as a "16 Meg x 16 x 8 Banks" device. The datasheet indicates this "128 Meg x 16" organisation only requires address bits A0 to A13.
The TI AM3359 Industrial Communication Engine (ICE) Schematic shows that ball T7 on the SDRAM U7 is connected to DDR_A14 on the AM3359 processor.
This means the AM3359 ICE EVM Rev2.1 PCB was designed to also accept higher density parts such as the MT41K256M16TW-093:P which is organised as 32 Meg x 16 x 8 banks, or twice times the capacity of the MT41J128M16JT-125. The MT41K256M16TW-093:P datasheet has Figure 7: 96-Ball FBGA – x16 (Top View) which shows ball T7 is A14 on the higher density part.

Thank you for your thorough response and clarification on the revision differences. I did confirm in the TI design files that the BOM lists the DDR3 as 96-ball, matching what you pointed out.
However, one additional observation: in the schematic, pin T7 is shown as connected, whereas the Micron DDR3 datasheet marks T7 as NC (No Connect). I wanted to bring this up in case you have insights on this specific discrepancy or its potential effect on the design. Thanks again for the valuable input!

@MohammedMubarak I have updated the answer to try and address your comment about ball T7 on the DDR3 device
